# JasperReport 6.0.3 Using Zxing to Generate QR Codes

Tags: java, jasper-reports, zxing

In my web app I was using JasperReport 4 and zxing jar to generate QR Codes. I have upgraded to JasperReports 6.0.3 and zxing 2.2 and now I get the following when trying to generate the report that worked previously:

```
00000026 JRFillSubrepo E net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport prepare Fill 1: exception
                             net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression : 
Source text : JRImageRenderer.getInstance(com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter.toBufferedImage(new com.google.zxing.qrcode.QRCodeWriter().encode($V{left_sn},com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,300 ,150 )), JRRenderable.IMAGE_TYPE_PNG, JRImage.ON_ERROR_TYPE_ERROR)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.evaluate(JREvaluator.java:262)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRCalculator.evaluate(JRCalculator.java:610)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRCalculator.evaluate(JRCalculator.java:578)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElement.evaluateExpression(JRFillElement.java:1015)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillImage.evaluateImage(JRFillImage.java:539)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillImage.evaluate(JRFillImage.java:519)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:258)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:454)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2023)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:753)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:263)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:123)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:539)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseReportFiller.fill(BaseReportFiller.java:393)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.fillSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:715)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRSubreportRunnable.run(JRSubreportRunnable.java:58)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.AbstractThreadSubreportRunner.run(AbstractThreadSubreportRunner.java:202)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:897)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:919)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:737)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRImageRenderer.getInstance(Ljava/awt/Image;BB)Lnet/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRRenderable;
at SeatRowMatrixLeftSubReportV6_2_1410891674951_480225.evaluate(SeatRowMatrixLeftSubReportV6_2_1410891674951_480225:195)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.evaluate(JREvaluator.java:249)
... 19 more
```

Comment: I wrote an answer using `zxing` to generate the QR code in [Stack Overflow: qr-code-integration-in-jasperreport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29786226/qr-code-integration-in-jasperreport/47383846#47383846). If suits your requirement you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

The JRImageRenderer method that you were using has been removed several versions ago.

An equivalent expression would look something like the following:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.RenderableUtil
    .getInstance($P{JASPER_REPORTS_CONTEXT})
    .getRenderable(
        com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter.toBufferedImage(
            new com.google.zxing.qrcode.QRCodeWriter().encode(
                $V{left_sn},
                com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,300 ,150
            )
        ), 
        net.sf.jasperreports.engine.type.ImageTypeEnum.PNG,
        net.sf.jasperreports.engine.type.OnErrorTypeEnum.ERROR
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the next code in your Jasper, If you need generate a pdf since Java application with JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(inputStream, parameters, JrDatasource):
com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter.toBufferedImage(new com.google.zxing.qrcode.QRCodeWriter().encode($P{parameter_QR},com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,300,300))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In addition is necessary import the jars, used to create the QR code in your project too (zxing-core, zxing-javase, barcode)